# TF14045: The identity with type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity' could not be found

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

Azure DevOps

Pipelines -> Releases -> Edit Pipeline -> Add Task -> Deploy Azure App Service ->

Chose Azure Subscription -> Authorize -> Entered Sign In Credentials -> 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR with this message: TF14045: The identity with type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity' could not be found.

Can't authorize to add the Deploying service...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Active Directory > App registrations > New Registration
Name: [VSTS Name]
Accounts in this organizational directory only
Redirect URI (optional): https://VisualStudio/SPN

In this app registration go to Certificates & Secrets > Client Secrets

Add a new secret (any expiration, any description) after saved copy the [value] generated.

Go to subscription > Access Control > Add your app as owner
search for your[VSTS Name]

Go back to VSTS and select the option "use the automated version of the service connection"

copy Service principal client ID and Tenant ID from the AD

Service principal key is the [value] (Client Secret)

Comment: Nice, any idea how to do this now, two years later? Last three steps, starting at go back to VSTS? is this DevOps?

Comment: I followed this solution, and it worked for me: https://edi.wang/post/2019/2/13/fix-azure-devops-tf14045-error-when-deploy-to-azure

Comment: @BHANG Yep, Azure devops was previously called VSTS aka visual studio team services